# Nested angular components in projects with multiple modules like JHipster

Tags: angular, module, components, jhipster, shared

I'm trying to show an entity component in another Entity component.

I found some information about shared modules online, I also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284351/jhipster-4-how-to-put-entity-component-list-on-home-screen) but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it gets a little bit complicated when you have multiple modules in your project. In a project like the ones generated by JHipster there are several modules in the project.

But no worries, the solution is easy:

Assuming the entity component supposed to get displayed inside another component is **ReviewComponent** and also assuming there is a review.module for all the Review-related components, you should export ReviewComponent in review.module:

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [ByubSharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES)],
    exports: [
        ReviewComponent
    ],
    declarations:...
```

And let's say the component which is supposed to display ReviewComponent inside is **BusinessComponent** and there is a business.module for Business-related components. You should import the Review module into it:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ByubSharedModule, ByubReviewModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES)],
    declarations: [...
```

Then you’ll be fine to use the selector in any Business-related html component

Comment: @Juan Pablo, Could you show me the code so I can understand better?

Comment: @Alireza I'm facing a problem very similar to this, however, I can't manage to solve using your logic. Could you take a look? Tks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952267/using-components-from-another-module-on-a-angular-jhipster-application

Comment: @TinMegali Sorry for the delay in reading your comment. I just noticed that you solved the problem. Not sure what it really was. Never had such a problem with exporting const or the order of importing route and module,  but I'm glad you managed it. Different bugs come with different versions :)