# Why importing entity module in another is breaking the feature in Jhipster

Tags: angular, typescript, module, jhipster

I m training my self on angular, in Jhipster 6.3.1.

I generated a small application with some relationships, where  I have a `many to one` relation between `Boxer` entity and `Picture`

Then I got the Idea of using the  `Picture` edit component inside the `Boxer` edit component. To achieve this I believed that exporting the the `Picture` edit component in it feature module and import this last one in the `Boxer` module should be enough to use it in the edit form as below

```
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="boxingApp.boxer.picture" for="field_picture">Picture</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="field_picture" name="picture" formControlName="picture">
                        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                        <option [ngValue]="pictureOption.id === editForm.get('picture').value?.id ? editForm.get('picture').value : pictureOption" *ngFor="let pictureOption of pictures; trackBy: trackPictureById">{{pictureOption.title}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            <jhi-picture-update></jhi-picture-update>
```

but I m surprised to see that when I m importing the `Picture` module in the `Boxer` all My Boxer components are replaced by Picture's ones

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BoxingSharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { BoxerComponent } from './boxer.component';
import { BoxerDetailComponent } from './boxer-detail.component';
import { BoxerUpdateComponent } from './boxer-update.component';
import { BoxerDeletePopupComponent, BoxerDeleteDialogComponent } from './boxer-delete-dialog.component';
import { boxerRoute, boxerPopupRoute } from './boxer.route';
import { FilterByPipe } from 'ngx-pipes';
import { BoxingPictureModule } from '../picture/picture.module';

const ENTITY_STATES = [...boxerRoute, ...boxerPopupRoute];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BoxingSharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES),BoxingPictureModule],
  declarations: [
    FilterByPipe,
    BoxerComponent,
    BoxerDetailComponent,
    BoxerUpdateComponent,
    BoxerDeleteDialogComponent,
    BoxerDeletePopupComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [BoxerDeleteDialogComponent]
})
export class BoxingBoxerModule {}
```

the `Picture` module is as below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BoxingSharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { PictureComponent } from './picture.component';
import { PictureDetailComponent } from './picture-detail.component';
import { PictureUpdateComponent } from './picture-update.component';
import { PictureDeletePopupComponent, PictureDeleteDialogComponent } from './picture-delete-dialog.component';
import { pictureRoute, picturePopupRoute } from './picture.route';

const ENTITY_STATES = [...pictureRoute, ...picturePopupRoute];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BoxingSharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES)],
  declarations: [
    PictureComponent,
    PictureDetailComponent,
    PictureUpdateComponent,
    PictureDeleteDialogComponent,
    PictureDeletePopupComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    PictureUpdateComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [PictureDeleteDialogComponent]
})
export class BoxingPictureModule {}
```

in the picture below you can see that my routing is asking for Boxing pages but I m getting Picture management ones

[image: the routing is rendering the imported module]

If I remove `BoxingPictureModule` from the imports and the `<jhi-picture-update></jhi-picture-update>` It will return to normal

[image]

Please what is really happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your routing using Augury plugin, you will probably find that your boxer module now contains also the routes from picture module. And both have a basic route of ''. That means your picture routes override boxer routes.
Here is a better explanation [Using Components from Another Module on a Angular/JHipster Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952267/using-components-from-another-module-on-a-angular-jhipster-application)